# Insert Data to Mysql Through Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to insert data into the MySQL user table through node js, I am using 
and following 
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values

Below is my code, I don't really know what went wrong, I couldn't insert data through postData query, but it works if I try to execute the test query.

Why isn't the postData query working?

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host        : 'localhost',
    port        : 3306,
    database    : 'csc309',
    user        : 'root',
    password    : 'root'
});

connection.connect();

var postData = {username: 'user4', 
    firstname: 'first', 
    lastname: 'last', 
    password: 'password', 
    email: 'test2@email.com'};

/*  
var test = connection.query('INSERT INTO user (username, firstname, lastname, password, email) VALUES 
    ("user4", "first", "last", "password", "sdfsdf@hotmail.com")');
*/

var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO user VALUES ?', postData, function(err, result) {
    console.log('The solution is: ', result);
});
```

Here is my user sql user table.

```
create table user (
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(40) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    firstname varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    lastname varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    created_at datetime NOT NULL,
    email varchar(40) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    reputation int DEFAULT 0,
    mailing_address varchar(100),
    phone varchar(20),
    gender varchar(10),
    admin tinyint default 0 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert a row with explicitly specified values passing an object to a escaped query, you should use the `INSERT ... SET` form:

```
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?', postData, function(err, result) {
  console.log('The solution is: ', result);
});
```

The resulting query will look like:

```
INSERT INTO user SET `username` = 'user4', `firstname` = 'first', `lastname` = 'last', `password` = 'password', `email` = 'test2@email.com'
```

Comment: the test query works fine with or with out the callback, my question is why the postData query not working.

Comment: You question was very clear, but I totally misunderstood it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried both VALUES ? AND SET?, and it still wouldn't work. That is the weird part, am i missing something package?

Comment: Oh, nvm, I figured out myself, in the sql user table I set email as unique so  it wouldn't allow me to add user with the same email address....

Comment: Well, assuming that the test query worked, you've inserted a row in your table. That said, you should check the `err` variable, because you defined the `username` attribute as `UNIQUE`, so you can't insert another row with an already existent `username='user4'`.